# Awk to skip the blank lines

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

The output of my script is tab delimited  using `awk` as :

```
awk -v variable=$bashvariable  '{print variable"\t single\t" $0"\t double"}' myinfile.c
```

The `awk` command is run in a while loop which updates the variable value and the file myinfile.c for every cycle.
I am  getting the expected results with this command .
But if the inmyfile.c contains a blank line (it can contain) it prints  no relevant information. can I tell `awk` to ignore the blank line ?

I know it can be done by removing the blank lines from  myinfile.c before passing it on to `awk` .
I am in knowledge of `sed` and `tr` way but I want `awk` to do it in the above mentioned command itself and not a separate solution as below or a piped one.

```
sed '/^$/d' myinfile.c
tr -s "\n" < myinfile.c
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and replies.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There are two approaches you can try to filter out lines:

```
awk 'NF' data.txt
```

and

```
awk 'length' data.txt
```

Just put these at the start of your command, i.e.,

```
awk -v variable=$bashvariable 'NF { print variable ... }' myinfile
```

or

```
awk -v variable=$bashvariable 'length { print variable  ... }' myinfile
```

Both of these act as gatekeepers/if-statements.

The first approach works by only printining out lines where the number of fields (`NF`) is not zero (i.e., greater than zero).

The second method looks at the line length and acts if the length is not zero (i.e., greater than zero)

You can pick the approach that is most suitable for your data/needs.

Answer (score 11):

You could just add

```
/^\s*$/ {next;}
```

To the front of your script that will match the blank lines and skip the rest of the awk matching rules.  Put it all together:

```
awk -v variable=$bashvariable '/^\s*$/ {next;} {print variable"\t single\t" $0"\t double"}' myinfile.c
```

Answer (score 2):

may be you could try this out:

```
awk -v variable=$bashvariable  '$0{print variable"\t single\t" $0"\t double"}' myinfile.c
```

Comment: ur solution falters when row being read in contains only an `ASCII` `"0"`, `"-0"`,`"0.0000"` etc (basically anything `awk` tries to be too clever and interpret  it numerically on ur behalf) : `echo "0" | awk -v variable=$bashvariable  '$0{print variable"\t single\t" $0"\t double"}' < nothing gets printed. new shell prompt >
%`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -v variable=$bashvariable '/^.+$/{print variable"\t single\t" $0"\t double"}' myinfile.c
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this solution, so: `awk '!/^\s*$/{print $1}'` will run the block for all non-empty lines.
`\s` metacharacter is not available in all awk implementations, but you can also write `!/^[ \t]*$/`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

> \s Matches any space character as defined by the current locale. Think of it as shorthand for ‘[[:space:]]’.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Levon's answer, you may just add  `| awk 'length { print $1 }'` to the end of the command.

So change

```
awk -v variable=$bashvariable  '{ whatever }' myinfile.c
```

to

```
awk -v variable=$bashvariable  '{ whatever }' myinfile.c | awk 'length { print $1 }'
```

---

In case this doesn't work, use  `| awk 'NF { print $1 }'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` way of only trimming out actually zero length lines but keep the ones with only spaces tabs is this :

> ```
> awk 8 RS=
> ```

just doing `awk NF` trims out lines 3 (`zero length`) and 5 (`spaces and tabs`) …..

```
 1   abc 
 2  def
 3  
 4   3591952
 5          
 6   93253
         1   abc 
         2  def
    
         3   3591952
         4          
         5   93253
 
 1   abc 
 2  def
 3   3591952
 4   93253
```

but the `RS=` approach keeps line 5 for u:

```
 1   abc 
 2  def
 3   3591952
 4          
 5   93253
```

** lines with `\013 \v VT :: \014 \f FF :: \015 \r CR` aren't skipped by default `FS = " "`, despite them also belonging to `POSIX [[:space:]]`